# What is the most optimal way to draw and add to a scene a large number of sprites(~200) in cocos2d-x v3?

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-x-3.0

The sprites are running an animation all the time they are being displayed.

I have tried:

- Creating and adding them to the scene on the fly and some of them experience a noticeable lag when they are added to the screen.
- Creating them before hand and keep them added in the scene but hidden. However when I position and display them, a noticeable lag freezes the game for less than a second.

These sprite frames and animation are loaded when the game starts in their corresponding cache from spritesheets and plist files.

Any ideas to minimize the lag? or any other approach?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have to use "Spine" to add multiple/large no. of Animations into a scene. Cocos2dx3.x support "Spine" api i.e "cocos2d-x-3.10/cocos/editor-support/spine".
And here are some good examples:-
[spine-runtimes](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/spine-runtimes/tree/master/spine-cocos2dx/3)